# "Radius" in the square metric

Tags: general-topology

In the square metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, defined by $d(p,q) = \max\limits_{i=1, \ldots n} |p_i - q_i|$, open balls end up being open squares which are the same distance from some fixed point. My question is: what exactly is the "radius" of such an open ball? I've always thought it was the same length, but I'm reading conflicting material that suggests it's in fact the length from the center to the vertex of the square. I'm trying to relate the Euclidean metric to the square metric and define a relationship between their respective open balls, but this only makes sense if the side length (or half of it) is the radius.

Comment: I do not understand the question. For any metric $d$ the radius of the open ball $B_r(p) = \{ q \in \mathbb R^n \mid d(q,p)< r \}$ by definition is $r$. Or do you mean the diameter with respect to the Euclidean metric?

Comment: @KritikerderElche I'm trying to understand the connection between the radius of an open ball and the side length of a square. The hint for understanding how to find an open ball in the square metric within an open ball in the Euclidean metric I've seen is to consider the $n=2$ case and consider a square inscribed in a circle.  I can figure out the geometry in such a case, but I don't understand which length I'm looking for as the radius.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed e.g. in $\Bbb R^2$, we have that $B_d((0,0),1) = (-1,1) \times (-1,1)$ and so **by definition** the radius of this square is $1$ (because the distance must be less than $1$ (to the origin) to be inside the ball). The $d$-diameter of this set (where $\operatorname{diam}_d(A)=\sup\{d(x,y)\mid x,y \in A\}$) is $2$, just as the Euclidean unit ball has diameter equal to the doubled radius). So the $d$-radius of a ball is just by definition the $r$ used in its definition.

If $d_e$ is the usual Euclidean distance on $\Bbb R^n$, we have the obvious inequalities (for all $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$):

$$d(x,y) \le d_e(x,y) \le \sqrt{n}\cdot d(x,y)$$

which leads to (all points $x$ and $r>0$)

$$B_{d_e}(x,r) \subseteq B_d(x,r)$$ and

$$B_{d}(x,\frac{r}{\sqrt{n}}) \subseteq B_{d_e}(x, r)$$

which shows that every ball of one type includes a ball from the other type, and leads to the conclusion that the metrics are equivalent.

Comment: When you say by definition that the radius is $1$, are you looking at the distance to the vertices (or half the diagonal) or half the side length? This distinction is my primary confusion.

Comment: @JohnT I look at the definition of the set.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a bit confused. The definition requires that every point have distance $<r$ from the center $(0,0)$, but if the square has side length $s$, the diagonal of the square is length $\sqrt{2}s$ and the length from the original to a vertex is half of that, which is $\frac{\sqrt{2}s}{2} = \frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}$. I'm not sure how to extract the radius from this.

Comment: @JohnT If a set is defined as the set of points that are distance $<s$ from some fixed point, **by definition** the radius of that set is defined to be $s$ (and we call that fixed point a centre). This has nothing to do with lengths of sides etc. Metric topology is not geometry and we don't care about lengths of sides or diagonals, these notions don't exist in topology at all.  We only care about these sets because they are the base for the topology.

Comment: Though this makes more sense, I thought the intuition for $B_d (x, r/\sqrt{n}) \subset B_{d_e} (x,r)$ is the geometry in $\mathbb{R}^2$, showing that the side length of a square inscribed in a circle of radius $r$ is $r/\sqrt{n}$. Is there a different way you came up with this? Or is there a natural relationship between the side length and the radius?

Comment: @JohnT no it’s just arithmetic of the formulas.